# Restoring an older iPad - Not showing in the Finder.app

Tags: ipad, finder

I'm trying to restore an older iPad (with home button), to factory settings. It will go to my grandchildren. I've taken these steps as described in this [Apple support document][1]:

I have shut off the device

I restarted holding the home button.

I see the connect to computer screen.

The iPad does not show in the Finder. sigh

I saw it in the Finder earlier, but had to restart the computer and iPad to resolve a network problem.

I've tried different computers. Different USB cables.

Not sure what else to try.

I'd appreciate any help.

Meanwhile, is there a way to charge a locked iPad?

Thanks
[1]: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211078

Comment: You are currently asking whether/how it is possible to charge an iPad, while I am pretty sure you want to know how to resolve this issue. Charging a locked iPad always works as far as I know (plug it in, done).

Comment: Plugging it in doesn't work - You can't charge these days until you unlock the device. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: make sure to use apple cable to see if that makes a difference.  with computer on and finder open and cable connected to computer, plug in iPad and try a hard reset on the iPad and see if it comes up(shows).

Comment: Thanks a ton. Putting into restore mode, than doing a hard reset allowed the device to show in the Finder! Fingers crossed on the restore!

Comment: Update - The restore worked as well. Thanks to all.